# Prevent page flash in Next.js 12 with Tailwind CSS class-based dark mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

How can one prevent the page flash when using class-based dark mode in Tailwind CSS with Next.js v12 without using any 3rd party pkgs like next-themes?

I've looked at:

- this Q&A [How to fix dark mode background color flicker in NextJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67094919/how-to-fix-dark-mode-background-color-flicker-in-nextjs) and while it's a valid/working solution in Next.js <v12, in v12 it no longer works and throws warnings in dev which suprisingly turn to a build blocking error in prod env
  `Do not add <script> tags using next/head (see inline <script>). Use next/script instead.  See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-script-tags-in-head-component`
- This article https://www.vidyasource.com/blog/dark-mode-nextjs-tailwindcss-react-hooks however including the script `<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" src="/scripts/darkMode.js"/>` still results in a page flash as it adds `defer` to it in the `head`
- This official Tailwind CSS dark mode doc on what's required https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually

```js
// On page load or when changing themes, best to add inline in `head` to avoid FOUC
if (localStorage.theme === 'dark' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
} else {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
}
```

I think they restrict putting things in `Head` from v12 to prepare for Suspense / Streaming / React v18.

Either way, I'm lost on how to do it without next-themes, does anyone know how can we just inject that bit of script to prevent that page flash?

Hope this question makes sense, if not, please give me a shout.

I like simple and minimalistic things, hence the aim to reduce the dependency on 3rd party pkgs, such a simple thing should be possible without overcomplicated solution IMO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it like this in Next 12.1.0:

1. Create `theme.js` within the `public` folder (mine has the following content):

```js
;(function initTheme() {
  var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light'
  if (theme === 'dark') {
    document.querySelector('html').classList.add('dark')
  }
})()
```

2. Add `<Script src="/theme.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />` to `_app.tsx` or `_app.jsx`. This is important - I tried putting it inside `_document.tsx` which didn't work. The final `_app.tsx` looks like this:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Script from 'next/script'

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <>
    <Head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    </Head>
    <Script src="/theme.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
}

export default App
```

Works like a charm for me - no flickering and all Next.js magic. :) Hope this works for you too.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.` when refreshing the page - any ideas?

Comment: @jimmyNames were you able to fix that hydration failed issue?

Comment: @RonaldBluthl the Next.js docs say that `beforeInteractive` only works from `_document`, did you encounter any issues? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#beforeinteractive

Comment: @jimmyNames I believe this is since the v12 update, I had this solution in place before and had no issue but since 12 I'm seeing this console log as well. It looks like we'll need to find a solution or live with the temporary error.

Comment: @Noitidart yes in the end the error was resulting for me due to the dark mode library i was using, in the end i followed their documentation and resolved the bug

Answer (score 7):

NextJS 13 with App Router:

After looking at the Page Source Code for the Twailwind website directly (by clicking `command+option+u` on Chrome MacOS), we can see that they are using the exact strategy they describe in their [Dark Mode documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode).

However, combining this with [NextJs' Inline Script Optimizations](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts#inline-scripts) will not work because they wrap the content of inline scripts inside a call to next_js, which ultimately requires the page to load NextJS before setting the dark mode (hence the FOUC).

To avoid this, we can use a plain `script` tag without optimization inside our **root** layout and set its content using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property like so:

```
<html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
  <head>
    <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
        try {
          if (localStorage.theme === 'dark' || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
          } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
          }
        } catch (_) {}
      `
    }}/>

    {/* Other Meta Tags, Links, Etc... */}
  </head>
  
  <body className="text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400 bg-white dark:bg-slate-900">
    {/* Content */}
  </body>
</html>
```

That way, our script will be one of the first to execute when the page loads, preventing a flash of unstyled content.

**[EDIT]**:

This approach causes NextJS to throw a `Prop 'className' did not match` warning in dev mode when the "dark" class is present in the client HTML but not in the server-rendered HTML. This is to be expected since we changed the structure of the HTML before NextJS had a chance to verify it. We can manually suppress the warning by setting `suppressHydrationWarning` on the opening HTML tag.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on @Fausto's answer:

NextJS 13 with App Router:

With the app router, there is a way to do this using fully server side rendering, but I had to go with @Fausto's approach, as I needed SSG. You can use the `cookies()` dynamic function in the `RootLayout` (since that can be an async function itself), and then the theme will be applied to the html prior to the page being rendered.

```
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const theme = cookieStore.get("theme");

    return (
        <html lang="en" data-theme={theme}>
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In nextjs 13 it should work in the _document.tsx in the Pages Router if you write it like this:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head >
        <Script src="/theme.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
      </Head>
      <body 
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```